# Don't understand Array anymore. No clear circular array around empty. Size Problem

Tags: modifiers, empty

Rotate Empty with 360/6 to get a 6 spoke rim, but the elements are everywhere with increasing sizes. I didn't activated it. Where does this come from?

[image]

Comment: If the empty has transforms before you atteched it to the modifier or if the object has transforms they also matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the scale of the empty and put it at the same position as the object's origin